# py.test fixture how can I change fixture's scope

Tags: python, pytest, xdist

I am running tests in two modes: with bare pytest and with pytest-xdist.
I have a heavy fixture that was defined with module scope. Inside this fixture, I have some optimization for the case when I am running tests with xdist:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def myfixture(request):

    if running_with_pytest:
        pass
    else:
        pass
```

It works fine, but I also want to change fixture's scope to `session`(if I run tests with xdist).

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi, perhaps did you find a way to tackle this issue. I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I gave a really good try to command line options, but it seems that fixture param `scope` only accepts string value, can't take callable function:
https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1682

I guess just need to wait until the issue is resolved.
But if you figure this one out please share your solution.